# Keras RStudio custom loss function

Tags: keras, rstudio

I am using the keras R package in RStudio. 
I want to fit a model that uses a customized loss function; specifically, (-1)* log-likelihood for a Poisson model. I am smoothing the logarithm as ln(0.0001 + x^2)/2. Following the example in [this article](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/sequential_model.html) I write

```
K <- backend()

poisson <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  K$sum(y_pred - y_true * K$log(y_pred^2 + 1e-4)/2 + lgamma(y_true+1))
}
```

Here I am mixing functions used by Keras from the "backend" source, such as K$log, and R function, such as lgamma, which I used because K$lgamma threw an error. 
The rest of the commands in the example did run and produced some output.

Questions:
1) Can one mix and match functions in keras running in RStudio? 
2) How can I test what the function is doing? I tried

```
poisson(1:5,3:7)
```

And I get the error

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it’s a bad idea mix both R and Keras function in custom loss function and here why: y_true, y_pred it’s not R vectors, but Keras tensors and this is source of your error.

Comment: Actually you might be able to do it by converting to R vectors and back using the K$eval() and K$constant() functions. Take a look at https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/59